# Found default.rdp in documents and some unusual logs - is this suspicious?

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

I've never used Remote Desktop Connection, yet I found a default.rdp file in Documents.

However I can't guarantee that I have never opened remote desktop by accident which may have created this file.

So I looked up where the log files are and looked at these files:

```
Microsoft-Windows-RemoteApp and Desktop Connections%4Admin.evtx
Microsoft-windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RemoteDesktopSessionManager%4Admin.evtx
Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager%4Admin.evtx
Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager%4Operational.evtx
```

In `Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager%4Operational.evtx` there are logs that say `Remote Desktop Services: Session logon succeeded`, even though I never use this application. Sometimes it's my own user name, sometimes it's one I don't recognise, seemingly a random string of characters followed by /Administrator. Each time the source is `LOCAL`.

Is this anything I need to worry about?

Comment: 1. Do the events coincide with when you login or perform an operation that requires security elevation? 
2. What is the other username? 
3. Could you check local `users and groups` in `computer management` 
http://letitknow.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/how-to-start-computer-management-in-windows-8/

Comment: David, thanks for your reply. 1) I'm not sure, the most recent log is a few days back and I'm not sure what I was doing exactly on those times and dates. 2) 8JOS3AEHKTELP\Administrator 3) I do not appear to have a "local users and groups" in computer management.

Comment: Try to run `lusrmgr.msc`   http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=57     Do you have an up-to-date antivirus, is it running properly, and have you run a full scan recently?  You could also try malwarebytes (just the free version) and if that comes up with anything dubious.

Comment: Thanks. There is only my user account present. I have windows defender and malware bytes and have run full scans recently, and nothing came up. I'm run again to be sure though.

Comment: `default.rdp` is supposed to be in your Documents folder.  No need to worry about that.